# The disjoint union map of the stalk maps is continuous

Tags: sheaf-theory

Let $ X $ be a topological space. Let $ P $ and $ Q $ be two presheaves on $ X $, and let $ h\colon P\to Q $ be a morphism of presheaves. Let $ P_x $ be the stalk of $ P $ at $ x\in X $ and the same $ Q_x $. Let $ h_x\colon P_x\to Q_x $ be the unique map that makes
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
PU @>>> P_x\\
@V{h_U}VV @VV{h_x}V\\
QU @>>> Q_x
\end{CD}
$$
commute for every $ U\subset X $ open, where the horizontal arrows maps a section to its germ. Let
$$
\Lambda P\colon \coprod_{x\in X}P_x\to X
$$
be the obvious projection map $ (x,\mathbf g)\mapsto x $, and the same for $ \Lambda Q $. Finally, for $ U\subset X $ open and $ s\in PU $ let
$$
\underline s\colon U\to \coprod_{x\in X}P_x
$$
denote the map $ s\mapsto (x,s_x) $, and the same for any $ t\in QU $.

I'm trying to show that the coproduct map
$$
\Lambda h = \coprod_{x\in X}h_x\colon \coprod_{x\in X}P_x\to \coprod_{x\in X}Q_x
$$
is continuous, where disjoint union is equipped with the final topology with respect to the maps $ U\to \coprod_{x\in X}P_x $ or $ U\to \coprod_{x\in X}Q_x $ introduce above, but I do not have succeeded yet. Could someone prove me any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I've come to a solution. It wasn't that difficult in the end. The composite map
$$
U\xrightarrow{\underline s} \coprod_{x\in X}P_x\xrightarrow{\Lambda h} X
$$
is nothing but the map $ \underline{h_U(s)}\colon U\to \coprod_{x\in X}Q_x $.